# Detect the changes in a file and write them in a file

Tags: python, file

I produced a script that detects the changes on files that are located in a specific directory. I'm trying to write all these changes to a `changes.txt` file. For this purpose I'm using the `sys.stdout = open('changes.txt','w')` instruction.

The problem is that whenever I run the script and change a file in the directory and save it, an empty file called `changes.txt` is created. This file is never written!

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import time
import sys
from watchdog.observers import Observer
from watchdog.events import FileSystemEventHandler
sys.stdout = open('changes.txt','w')

class MyHandler(FileSystemEventHandler):
def on_modified(self, event):
    print "something happened!"


if __name__ == "__main__":
event_handler = MyHandler()
observer = Observer()
observer.schedule(event_handler, path='.', recursive=False)
observer.start()

try:
    while True:
        time.sleep(1)
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    observer.stop()
```

Comment: why don't you just open the file regularily and `f.write()` to it?

Comment: Maybe it could be better to rewrite your print function. Otherwise, generally, to store output of any script, we use `python.py > changes.txt`.

Comment: It's complicated... @NilsWerner

Comment: FYI, his seems to work when I run it.  I ran the script, created a file, and deleted a file, and ended up with three `something happened!` lines in `changes.txt`.   Are you checking `changes.txt` *after* your script exits?  Due to output buffering, you may not see any output in `changes.txt` until the file is closed.

Comment: So should I just paste that into the code and remove the st.dout?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd recommend something like

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import time
import sys
from watchdog.observers import Observer
from watchdog.events import FileSystemEventHandler

class MyHandler(FileSystemEventHandler):
    def __init__(self, f):
        self.f = f
    def on_modified(self, event):
        self.f.write("something happened!\n")
        self.f.flush()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    with open('changes.txt','w') as f:
        event_handler = MyHandler(f)
        observer = Observer()
        observer.schedule(event_handler, path='.', recursive=False)
        observer.start()

        try:
            while True:
                time.sleep(1)
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            observer.stop()
```

as you can see, the control over where your outputwill be written to has been handed to the caller (the one instanciating `MyHandler`) instead of the callee (`on_modified`).

This means you can also do

```
event_handler = MyHandler(sys.stdout)
```

and see the output instead of the output being put into the file.

An additional benefit: using a context manager you can be sure the file is closed properly, even if errors occurr.

Comment: Thank you very much but what if I want the script to save the output into the same file everytime, not write over the old one? And also number the something happened! eg. something happened! #1

Comment: Appending to files is in the Python docs, and the incrementor can be done in a `MyHandler` member variable.